# Как изменять размер загружаемой картинки или сделать уменьшенную копию?

Tags: php

Есть скрипт который загружает картинку

```
    <?php require ('../model/db.php');
function format($filename) {
    return end(explode(".", $filename));
}
if($_FILES['upload'])
{

    $userId = $_SESSION['log_usr'] -> id;
    if (($_FILES['upload'] == "none") OR (empty($_FILES['upload']['name'])) )
    {
        $message = "Файлы не выбраны";
    }
    else if ($_FILES['upload']["size"] == 0 OR $_FILES['upload']["size"] > 2050000)
    {
        $message = "Превышен максимальный размер файла";
    }
    else if (($_FILES['upload']["type"] != "image/jpeg") AND ($_FILES['upload']["type"] != "image/jpeg") AND ($_FILES['upload']["type"] != "image/png"))
    {
        $message = "Выберите JPG или PNG формат.";
    }
    else if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']["tmp_name"]))
    {
        $message = "Ошибка. Попробуйте еще раз.";
    }
    else{
        $name =rand(1, 1000).'-'.md5($_FILES['upload']['name']).'.'.format($_FILES['upload']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "img/".$name);
        $full_path = '/controllers/img/'.$name;
        $img_th    = 'img/'.$name;
        $senddb  = R::dispense('pictures');
        $senddb -> url = $full_path;
        $senddb -> user_id = $userId;
        R::store($senddb);
        $message = "Файл ".$_FILES['upload']['name']." загружен";
        $size=@getimagesize('img/'.$name);
        if($size[0]<50 OR $size[1]<50){
            unlink('img/'.$name);
            $message = "Файл не является допустимым изображением";
            $full_path="";
        }
    }
    echo $message;
}
?>
```

Каким образом можно изменить размер загружаемого изображения и сохранить его уменьшенной копией либо же переписать оригинал?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php

Comment: @Let'ssayPie,  is not a valid JPEG file при использовании GD. Много разных изображений перепробовал.

Comment: Ну правильно, если вы загружаете PNG а работаете с ним как с JPEG, то ошибки будут